# Identify users accessing hidden link in a website

Tags: css, web-crawler, user-agent

Recently I put some hidden links in a web site in order to trap web crawlers. (Used CSS visibility hidden style in order to avoid human users accessing it).

Any way, I found that there were plenty of HTTP requests with a reference of browsers which have accessed the hidden links.

```
E.g : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31"
```

So now my problems are:

(1) Are these web crawlers? or else what can be?

(2) Are they malicious?

(3) Is there a way to profile their behaviour?

I searched on the web but couldn't find any valuable information. Can you please provide me some resources, or any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/

Comment: please post this question on => **security.stackexchange.com**, this sister thread is specifically for these kind of questions!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a HTTP [user](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) agent. They are not malicious at all. It's following the pattern, for example `Mozilla/<version>`  and so on. A browser is a user-agent for example. However, they can be used by attackers and this can be identified by looking at anomalies. You can read this [paper.](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/hackers/user-agent-field-analyzing-detecting-abnormal-malicious-organization-33874)

> The Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) identifies the client software
>   originating the request, using a "User-Agent" header, even when the
>   client is not operated by a user.

The answer to your questions are, in order:

1. They are not web crawlers. They are user agents. Common term for a web developer.
2. Generally they aren't malicious but they can be, as I suggest, look at the paper.
3. I don't understand what you mean by profiling behaviour, they aren't malware!